# Lion version of vim crashing repeatably - caught deadly signal SEGV

Tags: macos

whenever I work on multiple files in different vim buffers/tabs and do a :w to save, vim crashes with a segmentation fault.

I'm using vim 7.3 that came long with Lion (Actually with SnowLeopard which later I upgraded to Lion).

Is this issue Lion specific or is this only affecting upgrade users? Any one seen similar issues.

I've been a linux user for most of the time but just bought a mac recently and also upgraded to Lion recently.

It's quite aggravating to spend so much money and now can't use vim :(

Comment: I upgraded my iMac from Snow Leopard to Lion and I am unable to reproduce the error that you are seeing. I was able to launch vim in three tabs with three different documents, make changes and write each one out without any errors.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with vim getting his with a SEGV when a shell escape is used. I am running 10.7.1. The SEGV occurs about 80% of the time (I am reluctant to do it enough to get reliable statistical averages, but the point is that it is not completely deterministic).

Comment: The *Vim* [bundled with Lion](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-107/) seems to be 7.3.0 (based on `included_patches` in [`src/version.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/vim/vim-47/src/version.c)). *Vim* 7.3 is currently at 7.3.285 ([285 patches](http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/)); some of those are fixes for crashes. Have you tried a non-Apple build of Vim (e.g. *[MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)* (snapshot 61 is based on 7.3.260) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) (can build *MacVim*, or (currently) 7.3.237-based tty-only *vim* and/or *Vim.app*).

Comment: A recent answer on a possibly related question on SO ([MacVim caught deadly signal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6447186/193688)) suggests that plugins with native extensions might the be culprit. Try disabling all your plugins and bringing them back one by one.

Comment: I have the same problem. However, I am not using any plugins and have completely blanked my vimrc file. Is there a fix? Makes me regret moving to Mac.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. SEGV when hitting enter on ":w" to save a file, sometimes, when multiple buffers are used and after having used :bn / :bd / :bp / :w multiple times on the different buffers.

Comment: I just compiled my own version of what appears to be 7.3.495 (using @ChrisJohnsen's metric from `src/version.c`; also it says so on the title screen).  I've been having the same issue as @ssice.  I'll post again in a few days if compiling my own vim resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two avenues when you have located a repeatable crash (and from the comments and discussions it sure looks like the shipping version is more crash than ideal for the latest shipping OS).

1. File a bug at bugreporter.apple.com - it's free if you sign up for a free developer account.
2. Use something like [homebrew](http://www.andrewvos.com/2011/07/23/upgrading-vim-on-os-x-with-homebrew/) to get a newer (or older) version of vim that isn't crashing.

Answer (score 1):

You could give [MacVim](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/) a go. I switched over a few months ago and haven't looked back. The package comes with an executable that you can drop in your $PATH (e.g., /usr/bin/) to launch it from BASH/Terminal by typing *mvim*. Obviously this is not the solution you were looking for, but MacVim works *exactly* like VIM and with the polish of a GUI.